# Bootstrap Affix (or similar plugin) doesn't work inside fixed elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix

My html structure is like that:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="stage hb-closed">
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="sticky" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">Affix box</div>
            <div>
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="home-broker closed">
    Another app
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W5U7q/2/

Somebody can help me?

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  Please be more specific as to what you need help with.

Comment: Affix doesn't work inside this html structure. However i can't change this strutcture. Did you see any solution? I believe the problem is in elements with fixed position.